# Как правильно произнести числительные? (2)

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, числительные, даты

*В 2002, 2003 годах.*
Как правильно произносятся числительные в данном случае? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

• *Две тысячи второй* и *две тысячи третий* — это составные порядковые числительные.

> При склонении составных порядковых числительных все слова сохраняют первоначальную форму, кроме последнего слова, которое изменяется по падежам как прилагательное.

*Когда?* — *в две тысячи **втором**, в две тысячи **третьем**.*

• О наращении: оно, конечно же, не нужно.

> **6.2.4. Порядковые числительные в виде арабских цифр без наращения падежного окончания**
> К таким числительным относятся:
> <...>
> 2. Даты (годы и числа месяца), если слово *год* или название месяца следует за числом. Напр.: *В 1997 году; 12 декабря 1997 года.* Не: *В 1972-м году; 12-го декабря 1997-го года*.

• Если после двух дат стоит слово "годах", то оформление записи должно быть таким:
**в 2002–2003 годах**.

*Среди прочих интересных публикаций хотел бы выделить цикл статей Е. Кореневской «Для тех, кому за 60», публиковавшихся **в 2002–2003 годах*** (А. Болочев. Если жить интересно — возраст не помеха // «Наука и жизнь», 2006).

• Произношение же будет таким: *в две тысячи втором* [пауза] *две тысячи третьем годах*.

[Порядковые числительные](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/chislitelnoe/poryadkovye-chislitelnye.html)
[Числа и знаки](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html?ysclid=lduluhdqtk728018193)

Comment: Вопрос ведь - как правильно произнести, а не написать.

Comment: "Дык" и читайте последнюю запись. Просто первый отвечающий требовал наращения. Мне и пришлось дополнительно объяснять, что оно не нужно.

Comment: Наращение - это элемент написания, а не произношения. Shampar предложил использовать правило о перечислении порядковых - так как оно соответствует по произношению и с визуальной подсказкой. Технически же здесь можно и запятую, и тире, это вообще неважно. Произношение в обоих случаях будет одинаковое.

Comment: В ответе *Shampar*’а правильное произношение числительных вообще не обозначено. Вот, в одном из переводов: *Это случилось в далёком **двух** тысячи втором году, – продолжил Билл...* Вот где собака порылась, а не в ошибочном наращении.

Comment: Не обозначено, потому что он предлагает аналогию по написанию. Весь остальной текст я не понимаю. Какие переводы? Что означает пример?

Comment: @Atoma Никакое наращение не поможет правильно отсклонять (и, соответственно, произнести) части составного порядкового числительного, записанного цифрами. Смысл вопроса: как произнести — в двух тысячи втором, или в двух тысячах втором, или в две тысячи втором?

Comment: Вопрос наращений значения не имеет. Не плохое наращение или хорошее наращение - а никакое наращение тут не значимо, тут просто два варианта написания. И я не пишу, что ответ Shampar идеален, я о том, что дискуссия с ним по наращениям (и правило про тире) просто вообще не связан с заданным вопросом.

Comment: Странно, почему мне не пришло уведомление, да и сам ответ я не видел. Конечно, произношение "в две тысячи втором". Насчёт записи, думаю, что и с тире, и с запятой норм. А с наращением засада: с одной стороны  есть "года", а с другой – в правиле, приведенном shampar, о годах не сказано... И ко всем: у данного ресурса справа есть разделы, поэтому лучше делать ссылки именно на них, а то вываливается общая страница, искать трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Правильному произношению должно помогать правописание.

Ответ: «В 2002-м, 2003-м годах».  Если один за другим следуют два порядковых числительных, разделенных запятой или соединенных союзом, падежное окончание наращивают у каждого из них.

https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html?ysclid=lduluhdqtk728018193